# Diagonalizing Quadratic Forms. Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

I have a question that reads:

> Diagonalize the quadratic form $A(x,y) = 3x^2 -12xy + 7y^2$ by completing the square.

What is diagonalization?  Is that when I should find the eigenvector matrix, say, $S$, find it's inverse $S^{-1}$, and then multiply it by some matrix in order to obtain a diagonal matrix that is easy to find powers of?

I think that's what it is.

Problem is, I guess I don't understand what it means by "completing the square".  I mean I know what completing the square is in, say, high school algebra, but I don't understand what it means in this context.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Diagonalisation is to write it without mixed terms $xy$. 
$$3x ^2-12xy+7y^2=3(x^2-4xy)+7y^2=3(x-2y)^2-5y^2$$

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that.  Thanks!  My new question is, why does that help?

Comment: Help what, this is a key step in the analysis of quadratic forms eg we see that the signature of this form is zero, something not obvious from the original form.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a new pair of variables, call them $u$ and $v$, each of which is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$, such that $A(u,v)$ does not contain cross terms (containing the product $uv$). If you write out $A$ as a quadratic form,
$$ A(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\-4 & 7 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$
If you diagonalize the matrix in the middle, the eigenvectors give you the linear combinations, and the eigenvalues are the new coefficients to $u^2$ and $v^2$.

Comment: Don't you have the transpose on the wrong side?

Comment: Well, not anymore.