# solution of x and y for non standard eclipse equation

Tags: geometry, quadratics

with my basic math knowledge and search I found out that for a standard eclipse equation $x^2 / a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$, we can find out $x$ and $y$ by setting $y$ and $x$ intercept $0$.
But if the equation is of the form $x^2 + xy + 41y^2 = n$, how do we make a standard formula for $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Maybe this would help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1011192/463578

Comment: Please correct "eclipse" to "ellipse". And try to use MathJax in formulas.

Comment: To compute the semi-axes of the ellipse, consider a generic line through the origin $y=mx$ and find its intersections $(x(m), y(m))$ with the ellipse as a function of $m$: minimum and maximum of $x(m)^2+y(m)^2$ will give you the squares of the semi-axes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in a more general form, your equation is of the form:
$${\alpha _1}{x_1}^2 + 2{\alpha _2}{x_1}{x_2} + {\alpha _3}{x_2}^2 = {\alpha _0}$$
which using the matrix notion, may be written as:
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x_1}}&{{x_2}} 
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\alpha _1}}&{{\alpha _2}} \\ 
  {{\alpha _2}}&{{\alpha _3}} 
\end{array}} \right]\left[ \begin{gathered}
  {x_1} \hfill \\
  {x_2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right] = {\alpha _0}$$
Now, assuming a general linear transformation of the form $Y = LX$, where $X = \left[ \begin{gathered}
  {x_1} \hfill \\
  {x_2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right]$, one may re-write the original equation as:
$${Y^{\text{T}}}{\left( {{L^{ - 1}}} \right)^{\text{T}}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\alpha _1}}&{{\alpha _2}} \\ 
  {{\alpha _2}}&{{\alpha _3}} 
\end{array}} \right]{L^{ - 1}}Y = {\alpha _0}$$
Using eigen-decomposition, the symmetric coefficient matrix could be re-written as:
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\alpha _1}}&{{\alpha _2}} \\ 
  {{\alpha _2}}&{{\alpha _3}} 
\end{array}} \right] = PD{P^{\text{T}}}$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Substituting in the equation on has:
$${Y^{\text{T}}}{\left( {{L^{ - 1}}} \right)^{\text{T}}}PD{P^{\text{T}}}{L^{ - 1}}Y = {\alpha _0}$$
By factoring, one may write the above as:
$$\left( {{P^{\text{T}}}{L^{ - 1}}Y} \right)D\left( {{P^{\text{T}}}{L^{ - 1}}Y} \right) = {\alpha _0}$$
Since in the final form, no cross terms (e.g. ${y_1}{y_2}$) are allowed, one must enforce:
$${P^{\text{T}}}{L^{ - 1}} = I$$
which leads to:
$$L = {P^{\text{T}}}$$
So in summary, you should decompose your coefficients matrix, and the linear transformation matrix which is simply ${P^{\text{T}}}$ would transform your equation into your desired canonical form.

Comment: An older way of saying this: rotate the coordinates. In $x^2 + xy + 41y^2 = n$, the axes of the ellipse are slightly tilted with respect to the $x,y$ axes.